# Any group of even order has an element of order $2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Any group of even order has an element of order $2$.

I am trying to prove this...but I am not quite able to do it. My solution goes like this: If $G$ is a group of even order , then for every element in the group , there is an inverse.  But , since it is an  even order group we can pair up all the elements . So, how can we say that $\exists a\in G$ such that $ o(a)=2$?

How is this possible? I am not quite getting it...There is a similar question suggested in the comments but that does not answer my question as the user has shown a method and asked the community to verify whether it's a correct method or not .On the other hand, my question was entirely something different as I got stuck at one particular step and could not get any suitable conclusion for the problem and asked a different question altogether than the user and posted it in the community. . My question was not a verification one , but what I asked was that how dis we make such a conclusion if we go by the method (suggested by me) above . Thank you!

Comment: In any group, is there always an element that is of order 1? If so, what does this tell us about the remaining elements and their inverses? Can every remaining element have as its inverse a distinct element of $G$?

Comment: @user1090793 Ok... I do get what ur saying... so if we have one element of order 1 , we are left with odd number of elements and from those odd number of elements if we try to pair up their inverse with the corresponding elements , we will be left with one element which can't be paired up with any other elements in $\in G$ , so the conclusion should be that the "left up" element  has an inverse which is equal to that element only and hence order $2$ ,right?

Comment: @Martin R no...I have provided the reason in the original post...Thank you!...

Comment: I think it is helpful to learn about [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). For $p=2$ it gives you the result. This theorem is very basic for group theory, so you will need it anyway for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is in the right direction. In a group every element has its own inverse, but the inverse of the identity, $1$, is itself. So, excluding the identity, there are an odd number of elements left in the group. You can pair them up, but there will be one left. Let $a$ be this element. It must be its own inverse, and therefore, $a*a=1=a^2 \Rightarrow o(a)=2$

Comment: This fact is true iff any  two elements in a group never have the same inverse? Is this fact true?...

Comment: @Franklin Suppose that two elements, $a$ and $b$, have the same inverse, in other words, $ax=1=xa$ and $bx=1=xb$, for some element $x$. Then $axb=b \Rightarrow a=b$. Different elements always have different inverses.

Comment: @Franklin Yes, the Inverse of each element in a group uniquely exists.

Comment: @PauloSigiani Thanks a lot! I do get it now...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Consider the equivalence relation generated by $g\sim g^{-1}.$

- What is the order of the equivalence class of identity?
- What is the order of the equivalence class of a non-trivial element?

In the end, their sum must be the order of the group.